# PlayerPrefs won't save or load anything when I build the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple script that saves a text from an input field, like a "remember me" check box. It works fine on the editor. It saves, it logs correctly, it loads fine. But when I build the scene it doesn't work, it's like PlayerPrefs never saves anything. Anyone knows why?

```
    public Toggle rememberMe;
    public InputField fieldMail;
    public InputField fieldPassword;
    private string mail;
    private string password;
    private int rememberMeChecked = 0;
    private bool justChecked = false;
    public EventTrigger loginButton;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Checked")) { PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Checked", 0); }
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Mail")) { PlayerPrefs.SetString("Mail", string.Empty); }
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Password")) { PlayerPrefs.SetString("Password", string.Empty); }
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        rememberMeChecked = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Checked"); 
        mail = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Mail"); 
        password = PlayerPrefs.GetString("Password"); 

        if (!mail.Equals(string.Empty)) { fieldMail.text = mail; }
        if (!password.Equals(string.Empty)) { fieldPassword.text = password; }
        if (rememberMeChecked == 0) { rememberMe.isOn = false; }
        if (rememberMeChecked == 1) { rememberMe.isOn = true; }
        justChecked = rememberMe.isOn;
        rememberMe.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { 
            justChecked = !justChecked;
            if (justChecked) { Save(1); }
            else { Save(0); }
            LogInfo();
        });
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        fieldMail.text = mail;
        fieldPassword.text = password;
        if (rememberMeChecked == 0) { rememberMe.isOn = false; }
        if (rememberMeChecked == 1) { rememberMe.isOn = true; }
    }

    public void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log("PlayerPrefs saved.");
        LogInfo();
    }

    public void Save(int rememberMeChecked)
    {
        switch (rememberMeChecked)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("Mail", fieldMail.text);
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("Password", fieldPassword.text);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Checked", rememberMeChecked);
            }
            break;
            case 0:
            default:
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("Mail", string.Empty);
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("Password", string.Empty);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Checked", rememberMeChecked);
            }
            break;
        }
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Is `OnButtonClicked` ever called? Maybe try to immediately call the `PlayerPrefs.Save` within your `Save` method

Comment: You only seem to set the player prefs in start. In which case they kinda aren’t changing.

Comment: @derHugo yeah it is when you click the login button. Already tried that, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @BugFinder Yes but I add a Listener to the thing, so wouldn't this be called always?

Comment: Listeners can be funky with delegates. Could be using an old value of a variable or something. Try doing things more manually to see if that fixes it. Side note, you don't really need to do the lines in Awake(). When you do PlayerPrefs.GetInt and such you can just specify a default value. If that player pref doesn't exist, it'll use the default value.